# maven install shows error but when i execute maven -X install build success

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a java maven application when i execute the command mvn install it shows compilation error stating that the particular user defined package is not found. When i execute build maven from eclipse by passing -X clean install in goals it passes.

I am passing an User-defined Java object to the method as parameters(I am using the same process for different method with the same object it worked) but wen i create a new method it fails.
maven 3.5 version

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you try `mvn clean install` instead? That will clean up the target folder and start a fresh build.

Comment: i tried with that in Jenkins server though it fails

Comment: Can you show us the error output you get?

Comment: COMPILATION ERROR : 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/rathishkumar/newCheckout/Test/usercreation/src/main/java/com/utils/CreateUserUtils.java:[20,54] package com.utils.Bean does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:05.380s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 05 00:13:27 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 176M/1570M

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue was with the pom.xml where they build two different goals one to compile the main files and the other is to compile class files. I wrongly added the test beans to main project rather than it must be in test side. So, at the time of compilation first it compiles the main files these test beans binaries would not be available in the heap so it fails. 
now the issue has been resolved. Thanks for the help @DarsanMetha and @khmarbaise